# Compute bits per second

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic, computational-complexity

We know a computer can code 1024 bits/sec using a RSA modulus of 1536 bits and the running time of modular exponential with modulus $n$ is $O(\ln^3(n))$.

Using a key of 2048 bits, how many bits per second will code that computer?

Comment: Encrypting a certain number of bits per second does not really make sense relative to how RSA is used in practice. If you have any significant amount of data to encrypt, you run the RSA primitive _once_ to encrypt a symmetric key for a cryptosystem such as AES, and then the time dependency of the bulk encryption depends on the performance of AES, not RSA.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are told that the encryption rate decreases with a factor $\ln^3 n$, so compare $\ln^3 1536$ and $\ln^3 2048$

Comment: What should I do after that? Dividing 1024 by that result?

Comment: Yes.  Rates are inversely proportional to running time.